# How to modify (.+?) to ignore \n, \t, or print integers only? (Regex - Python 3.x)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to retrieve the amount of funding from a website with the following `htmltext`:

```
</span></p></div></div><dl class="medium">
<dt>Funding:\n\t\t</dt>
<dd class="">10.000 &euro;</dd><dt>
```

I use regex with Python 3 and the following source code:

```
regex = '<dt>Funding:(.+?) &euro;</dd>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
print(price)
```

But it delivers only the following result:

```
['\\n\\t\\t</dt><dd class="">10.000']
```

If I try to include `\\n\\t\\t</dt><dd class="">` in the regex expression like this:

```
regex = '<dt>Funding:\n\t\t</dt><dd class="">(.+?) &euro;</dd>'
```

It just returns `[]`. Any other modification that I tried with `(.+?)` doesn't deliver any or a better result. How can I modify the `(.+?)` expression in order to get the following result for `print(price)`

```
['10.000']
```

Comment: You would be better off using an HTML parser...

Comment: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should absolutely use an HTML parser, but since I know nothing about them for this specific case you've shown the following should work:

```
regex = '<dt>Funding:.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*&euro;</dd>'
```

Why should you use an HTML parser? Because as soon as your HTML isn't formed exactly how you're expecting it you'll start getting incorrect results. Imagine for example using the above regex with the following HTML:

```
</span></p></div></div><dl class="medium">
<dt>Funding:\n\t\t</dt>   //start matching here
<dd class="">&euro;</dd>  //value is missing
</span>
...
</span></p></div></div><dl class="medium">
<dt>Funding:\n\t\t</dt>
<dd class="">&euro;</dd>  //matches the value from the next result down
</span>
```